# Getting Internal server errorHTTP 500 after trying to run wordpress with wampserver

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am new to PHP field, I have installed wamp server locally and tring to install wordpress with it. Wampserver is installed correctly and coming locally perfectly. Now I have downloaded the WordPress 3.9 version and  trying to run it with the wampserver but I am getting http :500 error. I have edited the httpd.conf file and activated mod_dir.so but still I am getting the error .... anybody please help.

Comment: Check your `error.log` file, or more specifically, left click wamp tray icon `->` PHP `->` error log.

Comment: then enable display errors instead (Same icon, PHP, PHP Settings, Tick display errors & restart wamp.)

Comment: Set `WP_DEBUG` in the `wp-config.php` to `true`, Example: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: @Adrian Preussi have made the configuration in the wp-config-sample.php and set define('WP_DEBUG', true); but still getting the error

Comment: Then go into your `.htaccess` File (if not exists, create it - Check the File extension when you save! Dont create an `.htaccess.txt`, the correct file name is `.htaccess`!) and put following line: `php_flag display_errors On`. If that not working, go into the `php.ini` and change here the `display_error` to `On`.

Comment: my problem is that when i am hitting localhost in the browser  the wamp server is showing  but when i am trying to navigate to the wordpress it is showing error

Comment: [Wed Apr 30 19:22:30.647706 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 4116:tid 1536] [client 127.0.0.1:51976] script not found or unable to stat: C:/wamp/cgi-bin, referer: http://lifehacker.com/188892/show-hidden-files-in-finder